# how do I sign sha1 signature in Django?

Tags: python, django, sha1, digital-signature

I have not really dug in deep into django and signatures

I am trying to create a signature based on a given requirements

i = my username, v = expiration, and s = signature

**i:** MYUSERNAME
**v:** UNIX TIMESTAMP + 2 hours
**a:** MY_API_KEY
**s:** SHA1 SIGNATURE that is ("i=MYUSERNAME&v=(UNIX_TIMESTAMP + API_KEY)")

What I have so far.

```
import hashlib
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time

now = datetime.datetime.now()
now = now + timedelta(hours=2)
seconds = time.mktime(now.timetuple())
seconds = seconds
API = "87df234207v4444444"
signature = hashlib.sha1()
signature.update("i=MYUSERNAME&amp;v=%s%s" % (seconds, API))
```

Then when I ping the url, I get a "Bad Signature" response

Again my knowledge in this area is limited, your help is much appreciated

and the valid iframe to get the correct code is `http://api.myurl.com/i=MYUSERNAME&v=UNIX TIMESTAMP + 2 HOURS&s=MY VALID SIGNATURE`

PDF Documentation

Imagine that we need to calculate the signature for the following URI:

http://framed.incloode.com/index.php?i=TEST&arg1=val1&arg2=val2&t=123
The method to calculate the signature is as follows:

- Go through the full list of parameters and the values,
- Append these into one long string HTML safestring,like a normal GET request,
  For the above URI this long string would end-up looking like this:  
  i=TEST&arg1=val1&arg2=val2&t=123
- To specify until when this link should be valid, a validity must be added.
  The validity is a UNIX timestamp – for a validity of 2 hours, the value time() + 7200 should be passed. This validity (parameter and value) must also appended to the string to sign.
  For the above URI this would now look like this:  
  i=TEST&arg1=val1&arg2=val2&t=123&v=1444567890  
  The requests in the initial URI should be replaced by this list.
- The above collected string is then decoded from HTML(htmlspecialchars_decode()) so one ends up with a string looking like this:  
  i=TEST&arg1=val1&arg2=val2&t=123&v=1444567890
- The “INCLOODE_API_SECRET” that you have been supplied with must be appended to this string:  
  i=TEST&arg1=val1&arg2=val2&t=123&v=1444567890**INCLOODE_API_SECRET**
- Then,finallytheSHA1checksumofthatstringmustbegenerated.Then,itis appended to the parameter/value list retrieved at step (3).  

    This could end up looking like this:    

    http://framed.incloode.com? i=TEST&arg1=val1&arg2=val2&t=123&v=1444567890&s=abcdef0123456789

Comment: I would strongly discourage you from sending the signature in the URL, **especially if you are not using SSL.**

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see from your description is that you are not grabbing the hex digest at the end, which I can only assume is what the server expects.  Send this value instead:

`hashed = signature.hexdigest()`

Otherwise please post the documentation for this web service and make sure you are honoring case requirements (you never know...)

Comment: yes in the url I do actually pass it as a signature.hexdigest. I'll post the documentation too